# Windows Defender Commercial Use

Tags: anti-virus

has anybody had any experience with using this program in a business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some context to this question?  Are you going to start a business using Windows Defender to search for Spyware or something?  [Windows Defender](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/defender/default.mspx) shipped inbox with Windows Vista, and is available as a separate download for Windows XP.  Works fine for spyware and is not an Antivirus program.

It is not a managed solution in case you need reporting at the business level, that's where you'd want to go with a commercial solution from [Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/business/index.jsp) or [McAfee](http://www.mcafee.com/us/enterprise/products/system_security/clients/anti_spyware.html) or with the Microsoft [ForeFront](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/en/us/default.aspx) line of products (which are focused at the Enterprise and do offer all of the centralized monitoring/reporting you would want in an enterprise environment).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it in use in a university setting.  I do not think though it was using any central management of any sort though.

It is just a basic user level piece of software. Nothing to be used or trusted as a primary tool in a large setting though.

Answer (score 0):

it works OK.  Most AV software contains this functionality as well.  Personally I've been impressed with Forefront as a replacement for defender, but we used defender alone for a while without incident